# How do I get the last element of a json list?

Tags: python

Here I'm trying to get the last m2id to print it into console.

```json
[{
    "m2id":"865199733949071370",
    "author":{
      "id":"862323352869797948"
    }
  },
  {
    "m2id":"865199658103078925",
    "author":{
      "id":"751742911682445312"
    }
}]
```

And here's the code I wrote for it. (r.json being the json above):

```py
data = r.json()
for id in data:
    id3 = id["id"][-1]
    print(id3)
```

Running the code gave me the last number of the first m2id, Which is not what I want.

Edit: data[-1]["id"] Worked. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: `data[-1]`? also don't use *id* as a variable name.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this
x = [{
"m2id":"865199733949071370",
"author":{
"id":"862323352869797948"
}
},
{
"m2id":"865199658103078925",
"author":{
"id":"751742911682445312"
}
}]

print(x[len(x)-1]["m2id"])

Output
865199658103078925